# Comparison of two `time` objects with different timezones

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time, pytz

I'm comparing two `time` objects with different timezones, and looks like it's actually ignoring the timezone, testing only the hour/minute/second components.

Let's create two `time` objects:

```
from datetime import time
import pytz

CET = pytz.timezone('CET')
Japan = pytz.timezone('Japan')

t1 = time(1,2,3, tzinfo=CET)
t2 = time(1,2,3, tzinfo=Japan)
```

Printing them, we see that they're pretty different:

```
datetime.time(1, 2, 3, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
datetime.time(1, 2, 3, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Japan' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
```

Now, let's compare them:

```
t1 == t2
#-> True
```

Ehm, what? How is it possible that Python treats them equal?

Comment: Probably related: [Comparing a time in UTC with a time in Eastern time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524165/comparing-a-time-in-utc-with-a-time-in-eastern-time-using-python?rq=1)

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @MattDMo, it's 2.7. Sorry :)

Comment: Derp's should be the correct answer, as it explains **why** the time objects are naive - they have no date associated with them, and can never be aware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of your time objects are "naive" according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo:

> A `time` object *t* is aware if `t.tzinfo` is not `None` and `t.tzinfo.utcoffset(None)` does not return `None`. Otherwise, *t* is naive.

```
print(t1.tzinfo, t1.tzinfo.utcoffset(None))
print(t2.tzinfo, t2.tzinfo.utcoffset(None))
```

Gives us:

```
(<DstTzInfo 'CET' CET+1:00:00 STD>, None)
(<DstTzInfo 'Japan' JST+9:00:00 STD>, None)
```

---

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

> A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects.

---

In other words: the objects have no date and so it cannot be determined whether or not daylight saving time applies. They're ambiguous, and running `t.utcoffset()` for either will return `None`. Which leaves the timezones being ignored entirely in the comparison because they're effectively meaningless.

Comment: even if the code had used `datetime`; it would be incorrect. `tz.localize()` should be used, to make a naive datetime object timezone-aware.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs regarding naive and aware time objects:

> A time object t is aware if t.tzinfo is not None and t.tzinfo.utcoffset(None) does not return None.

In your case, both `t1` and `t2` return `None` for `t1.tzinfo.utcoffset(None)` and `t2.tzinfo.utcoffset(None)`. Hence your objects are naive and not aware.

So effectively you're comparing '01:02:03' with '01:02:03' which is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `(t1,t1.tzinfo) == (t2, t2.tzinfo)` or `t1.strftime('%H %M %S %Z') == t2.strftime('%H %M %S %Z')` this to check equality.

[derp explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706834/887007) why Python treated t1 and t2 equal and also refer this [supported operations (Python docs)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.tzinfo).

**More references**:

According to [pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic),

> The preferred way of dealing with times is to always work in UTC,
>   converting to localtime only when generating output to be read by
>   humans.

[pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) shows the way to convert (using localize and/or replace) `naive time objects` to `aware time objects` and also present ways to perform arithmetic over time objects.